# How to populate html using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am setting up a website for my semester project and i need to populate the html from ajax response.
I am getting data of posts from database but i need to populate 5 jobs in a div.
i have tried different approaches but it doesn't help
when i am populating table it is working fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            // Detect pagination click
            $('#pagination').on('click','a',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var pageno = $(this).attr('data-ci-pagination-page');
                loadPagination(pageno);
            });

            loadPagination(0);

            // Load pagination
            function loadPagination(pagno){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Site/loadRecord/'+pagno,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        //console.log (response);
                        $('#pagination').html(response.pagination);


                        createTable(response.result,response.row);
                    }

                });
            }

            // Create table list
            function createTable(result,sno){

                for(index in result){
                    var id = result[index].id;
                    var title = result[index].title;
                    var detailText = result[index].detailText;
                    var headerImageName = result[index].headerImageName;
                    var publishedDate = result[index].publishedDate;
                    var publishedTime = result[index].publishedTime;


                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr += "<td>"+ headerImageName +"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+ title +"</td>";
                    tr += "</tr>";
                    $('#postsList tbody').append(tr);



                    //$('#test').append(article);
                }
            }
        });
```

but when i tried to change the table with template elements. it's not working

```
function createTable(result,sno){

                for(index in result){
                    var id = result[index].id;
                    var title = result[index].title;
                    var detailText = result[index].detailText;
                    var headerImageName = result[index].headerImageName;
                    var publishedDate = result[index].publishedDate;
                    var publishedTime = result[index].publishedTime;
                    var article='<article class=\"row section_margin animate-box\">';
                     article+='<div class=\"col-md-3 animate-box\">';
                    article+='<figure class=\"alith_news_img\"><a href=\"single.html\"><img src=\"<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/thumb_medium_5.png\" alt=\"\"/></a></figure>';
                    article+='</div>';
                    article+='<div class=\"col-md-9 animate-box\">';
                    article+='<h3 class=\"alith_post_title\"><a href=\"single.html\">Reading is not only informed by what’s going on with us at that moment</a></h3>';
                    article+='<div class=\"post_meta\">';
                    article+='<a href=\"page-author.html\" class=\"meta_author_avatar\"><img src=\"<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/author-avatar.png\" alt=\"author details\"/></a>';
                    article+='<span class=\"meta_author_name\"><a href=\"page-author.html\" class=\"author\">Steven Job</a></span>';
                    article+='<span class=\"meta_categories\"><a href=\"archive.html\">Politics</a>, <a href=\"archive.html\">News</a></span>';
                    article+='<span class=\"meta_date\">18 Sep, 2018</span>';
                    article+='</div>';
                    article+='</div>';
                    article+='</article>';

                    $('#test').html(article);
                }
            }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please tell is what is not working?

Comment: Please show me some more code of yours so that i can understand better.

Comment: 1) are you sure result is an array? Can you `console.log` it?
2) are you sure that `<div id='test'></div>' exist?`
3) use single quotes in HTML inside a variable, it will make escaping easier :)

Comment: this article variable is not populating

Comment: yes console.log has array and div exists

Comment: to append table is working fine. but this article is not populating

Comment: also.. your if is probably wrong. It should be `for(r in result){ var headerImageName = r. headerImageName;` ... etc.

Comment: results in the variables are ok.. i have checked in console.log

Comment: i just needs to populate html

Comment: <div id="test">

        </div>

Comment: try clear .text(" ") or .html(" ") then do .text(article) or .html(article) ?

Comment: above picture is where i am getting everything

Comment: and the second picture is the desired results

Comment: try clear .text(" ") or .html(" ").. no luck

Comment: any error in console?Ensure div ID !

Comment: no error in console

Comment: function createTable(result,sno){
    
    for(index in result){
     var id = result[index].id;
     var title = result[index].title;
     var detailText = result[index].detailText;
     var headerImageName = result[index].headerImageName;
     var publishedDate = result[index].publishedDate;
     var publishedTime = result[index].publishedTime;


     var tr = "<tr>";
     tr += "<td>"+ headerImageName +"</td>";
     tr += "<td>"+ title +"</td>";
     tr += "</tr>";
     $('#postsList tbody').append(tr);



     //$('#test').append(article);
    }
   }
  });

Comment: if i try to populate result in table it is fine. but not with other html

Comment: you used ajax? or just creating this html and populating it in div test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197661/discussion-between-abu-sufian-and-ricky).

Answer (score 0):

Populating with AJAX data there are a couple of steps you need to make:

1. Create the request on the frontend (in JavaScript - as I see, you use jQuery)
2. Handle the request on the server side (e.g. with PHP) - send the response to the frontend
3. Handle the response on the frontend

Heres a snippet with mock API request:

```js
// self calling function
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // AJAX request with GET action from the mock API source
  $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(data) {
    // creating the "table" with the received data
    createTable(data)
  });
})

function createTable(data) {
  var html = ''
  data.forEach(e => {
    // calling createTableRow() for each data item in the
    // received array
    html += createTableRow(e)
  })
  $('#test').append(html);
}

// adding content to the DOM
function createTableRow(result) {
  // create and return the HTML string filled with dynamic data
  return `<div><h2>${result.title}</h2><p>${result.body}</p></div>`
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

The snippet doesn't show how you handle the request on the backend, only how you create a request with jQuery (**$.get()**) and how you handle the response on the frontend (inside the **$.get()** callback with the **createTable()** and **createTableRow()** functions).

Comment: see the updated question. i am doing something wrong in populating html elements. Table is fine but i don't need table

Comment: @AbuSufian I don't see any of the variables in your HTML string template - everything is "baked in". So you define the variables (like **id**, **title**, etc), but they are not in the string in **var article**.

Comment: yes because variable is not the issue. I first needs to populate html

Answer (score 0):

You should use [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) and use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
function createTable(result,sno){
  $.each(result, function(i, val){
    var id = val.id;
    var title = val.title;
    var detailText = val.detailText;
    var headerImageName = val.headerImageName;
    var publishedDate = val.publishedDate;
    var publishedTime = val.publishedTime;

    $('#test').append('\
      <article class="row section_margin animate-box">\
        <div class="col-md-3 animate-box">\
          <figure class="alith_news_img"><a href="single.html"><img src="<?php echo base_url(\"assets/images/thumb_medium_5.png\") ?>" alt=""/></a></figure>\
        </div>\
        <div class="col-md-9 animate-box">\
          <h3 class="alith_post_title"><a href="single.html">Reading is not only informed by what’s going on with us at that moment</a></h3>\
          <div class="post_meta">\
            <a href="page-author.html" class="meta_author_avatar"><img src="<?php echo base_url(\"assets/images/author-avatar.png\") ?>" alt="author details"/></a>\
            <span class="meta_author_name"><a href="page-author.html" class="author">Steven Job</a></span>\
            <span class="meta_categories"><a href="archive.html">Politics</a>, <a href="archive.html">News</a></span>\
            <span class="meta_date">18 Sep, 2018</span>\
          </div>\
        </div>\
      </article>\
    ')
  })
}
```

I'm not sure why you didn't use the variable, but I hope this one is works for you

Comment: i am only trying to populate html. rest i will tune the code with actual variables

Comment: An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '"assets/images/thumb_medium_5.' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\sai\application\views\index.php

Line Number: 711

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sai\application\controllers\Site.php
Line: 14
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sai\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: i need to escape double quotes in ajax response.. rest is fine now it is not picking the correct classes of html elements

Answer (score 0):

The template was using class "animate-box" whose opacity was set to zero on page load and it is increasing to one on scroll for animation, so when i am passing same class to the div using ajax the opacity was set to 0 so i was unable to see the posts. The posts was there. 
Thanks for the help there is no issue in code.